# Upload image and description on Firebase using Kotlin

Tags: firebase, image, android-studio, kotlin, post

At the moment, my application uploads images on firebase, but I want to add a description of that image too. After that, I need to retrieve both image and description on Home Page. But I am stuck at the part where I also add upload the description of the image..

```
package com.giveandshareauth

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.nfc.Tag
import android.provider.MediaStore

import android.text.TextUtils
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.giveandshareauth.Fragments.HomeFragment
import com.giveandshareauth.Fragments.PostFragment
import com.giveandshareauth.R
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_post.*
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_post.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_registration.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_post.PostImage
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_post.PostInfo as PostInfo1

class PostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var filepath : Uri
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private var storagePostImages: StorageReference? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)
        storagePostImages = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference

        upload.setOnClickListener(){
            uploadFiles()
        }

        publish.setOnClickListener(){
            publishFiles()


        }
    }

    private fun uploadFiles() {
        var i = Intent()
        i.setType("image/*")
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an image"), 111)


    }

    private fun publishFiles(){
        

        if(filepath != null){
            var pd = ProgressDialog(this)
            pd.setTitle("Upload")
            pd.show()
            var imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Images/"+System.currentTimeMillis()); //Every time an image will be uploaded, it will have a unique name in Firebase
            imageRef.putFile(filepath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {param ->
                        pd.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"File uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {param ->
                        pd.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, param.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }
                    .addOnProgressListener {param ->    // how much percent of the file is uploaded
                        var progress = (100.0 * param.bytesTransferred) / param.totalByteCount
                        pd.setMessage("Uploaded ${progress.toInt()}%")

                    }

                        imageRef.downloadUrl
                    }

        }


        // val intent = Intent(this, HomeFragment::class.java)
        // startActivity(intent);


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode==111 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){
            filepath = data.data!!
            var bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver,filepath)
            PostImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }

    }



}
```

The activity has an upload and a publish button also an ImageView and an EditText
The publish button uploads the image on firebase, I assume I should add a new button that uploads the whole thing after the description is added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.HomeFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout_post"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/post_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/close_post_btn"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/close"
                        />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/save_post_btn"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/save"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout_post"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/PostImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_image_icon"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PostInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:hint="Describe your Giveaway..."
                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/publish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="249dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="404dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="517dp"
            android:text="publish" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/upload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="404dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="249dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="517dp"
            android:text="upload" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The code works perfectly, I added it just to show what I have so far. My problem is that Idk how to add a string to the database that represents the description of the photo uploaded